# Any smart idea for this gsub() problem? (HTML sanitization with Lua)

Tags: string, lua, gsub

I'm trying to write a function that sanetizes an HTML text. Problem definition:

```
function f(txt) return txt:gsub("%s","&nbsp;")
```

Now this works for the following:

```
f(" hello  buddy!") ---> "&nbsp;hello&nbsp;&nbsp;buddy!"
```

But according to HTML specification, only when there are two or more spaces, the extra ones need to be replaced with `&nbsp;`. So, a single space doesn't need to be replaced. If there are more, one space will not be converted, but the rest will be converted to `&nbsp;`. In other words I need a function that:

```
f(" hello  buddy!") ---> " hello &nbsp;buddy!"
f("   ") ---> " &nbsp;&nbsp"
f(" ") ---> " "
f("hello buddy!") ---> "hello buddy!"
```

Any idea how I can write f()?

Comment: Can you add a link to where this requirement can be found in the html spec?

Comment: Sure. Read this: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html also WYSWYG tools like DreamWeaver generate the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Notes concerning Alex's answer. Posted here so I can include formatted code.)

The first 4 gsub calls can be replaced with a single call which takes a lookup table as it's second argument. This is much faster than making 4 passes over the code.

```
function sanitize(txt)
    local replacements = {
        ['&' ] = '&amp;', 
        ['<' ] = '&lt;', 
        ['>' ] = '&gt;', 
        ['\n'] = '<br/>'
    }
    return txt
        :gsub('[&<>\n]', replacements)
        :gsub(' +', function(s) return ' '..('&nbsp;'):rep(#s-1) end)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

you might try something like

```
txt:gsub("( +)", function(c) return " "..("&nbsp;"):rep(#c-1) end)
```

Comment: It doesn't give the required output. Only the first space character is ignored. The rest should be converted to &amp;nbsp; (see the second expected result in the examples above)

Comment: Indeed, there was something wrong, now it returns the expected result, by keeping the first space character (any space: space, newline, tab )

Comment: ah! I see your point. %s doesn't just mean SPACE (char 32) it's also the other space characters line tab. Good point.

Comment: I found a solution. Replace "(%s+)" with "(% +)" and it works the way it's supposed to work (only SPACE (char 32) should be replaced with &nbsp;

Comment: I thought all space characters should be replaced. If only char(32) needs to be replaced, you can even drop the % before the space. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: You can also drop the parenthesis from the pattern. It captures everything by default anyway. If you really want to utilize a subcapture, then you could capture only the spaces beyond the first and eliminate the subtraction `txt:gsub(' ( +)', function (c) return ' ' .. ('&nbsp;'):rep(#c) end)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jpjacobs's hint using function, here is the complete function code plus an example:

```
---This function sanetizes a HTML string so that the following characters will be shown
-- correctly when the output is rendered in a browser:
-- & will be replaced by &amp;
-- < will be replaced by &lt;
-- > will be replaced by &gt;
-- \n will be replaced by <br/>;
-- (more than one space) will be replaced by &nbsp; (as many as required)
-- @param txt the input text which may have HTML formatting characters
-- @return the sanetized HTML code
function sanitize(txt)
    txt=txt:gsub("%&","&amp;")
    txt=txt:gsub("%<","&lt;")
    txt=txt:gsub("%>","&gt;")
    txt=txt:gsub("\n","<br/>")
    txt=txt:gsub("(% +)", function(c) return " "..("&nbsp;"):rep(#c-1) end)
    return txt
end

text=[[    <html>   hello  &bye </html> ]]

print("Text='"..text.."'")
print("sanetize='"..sanitize(text).."'")
```

Output:

```
Text='    <html>   hello  &bye </html> '
sanetize=' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;html&gt; &nbsp;&nbsp;hello &nbsp;&amp;bye &lt;/html&gt; '
```

Comment: Note that this way you repace tabs, newlines by spaces instead of keeping the original space-character, which may or may not be what you want. Aside of that, you can also chain the gsub commands like `txt:gsub(pattern1,replacement1):gsub(pattern2,replacement2):...`

Comment: You can also combine the first 3 into one:
    txt=txt:gsub("[%&%<%>\n]",{["&"]="&amp;" , ["<"] = "&lt;", [">"]="&gt;" , ["\n"]="<br/>", });
You can even add a metatable to the replacements table above to generate the charcode for other characters.

Comment: I like the idea of using the table. Very smart indeed! :) Just one thing to keep in mind about sensitization in general: we need to take care of ampersand (&) first if we do it after then it will affect the markups we put before, i.e &nbsp; &lt; &gt; so the order of the members in this table, or the above function call is important.

Comment: The order of operations only matters if you make multiple passes over the text. If you do it in a single pass (via function or lookup table), order doesn't matter; the inserted `&` won't be re-processed during that pass (behavior like that would be a nightmare).  This is fortunate, because the order of elements in a table is completely irrelevant anyway; hashtables are not ordered, and even if they were the gsub operation wouldn't be affected.